Customizing the Bibliography in LaTeX According to IEEE Editorial Style Manual (German)
I am currently writing a document in LaTeX. I would like to customize the bibliography to suit my needs.
Currently, the output looks like this:
J. Briskman. ”2024 State of Mobile - The App Market Bounced Back in 2023 and
is Primed for a Record-Breaking 2024.“ (2024), [Online]. Verfügbar unter: https:
//www.data.ai/en/insights/market-data/state-of-mobile-2024/ (Zugriff
am: 10.07.2024).
But I would like to adjust it to look like this:
J. Briskman. 2024 State of Mobile - The App Market Bounced Back in 2023 and
is Primed for a Record-Breaking 2024. 2024. [Online]. Verfügbar unter: https:
//www.data.ai/en/insights/market-data/state-of-mobile-2024/ (Zugriff
am: 10.07.2024).
This style should be based on the IEEE Editorial Style Manual (German). Here are my packages:
\documentclass[captions=tableheading, listof=leveldown, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,head=25pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
url = {[Online]. Verfügbar unter:}
} %ändert den Text bei Onlinequellen im Literaturverzeichnis zu 'Abruf vom'
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{Zugriff am:\space#1}}

I hope you have an idea of how this can be solved! Thanks in advance :)
